# Hover issues with pure css displaced tooltip

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to create a pure css tooltip using html like this

```
<div class="divWithTooltip"> i haz tooltip 
    <span class="tooltip"> i am tooltip</span>
</div>
```

The tooltip should only be made visible when hovering over `.divWithTooltip`.

But I would like the user to be able to scroll through the tooltip as well.
So the idea is to let the user move the cursor from the `.divWithToolTip` to the tooltip in order to keep the tooltip visible. 
(*so in conclusion, when `.divWithTooltip` has been hovered over, the tooltip should change to some state where it also is shown on self hover*)
I'm transitioning the opacity for 0.5 seconds to keep the tooltip showing for a while after `divWithTooltip:hover`, but beyond that I haven't figured out what to do.

**Is it possible to solve this using pure CSS or would it require Js?**

my code  so far http://jsfiddle.net/oat19ncp/

I've also got a basic css hover issue with the code.
the tooltip always visible if the user hovers over it. I guess it's inherited the `:hover` rule from it's parent. How do I fix that?

Comment: I've checked your jsfiddle and it's working fine for me exactly the way you want it to work. I can hover over the divWithTooltip and the tooltip shows up. I can then move the move over the tooltip and it's still there where I can scroll and read through.
That said, there's one issue. If I scroll over where the tooltip is without scroll over divWithTooltip, the tooltip still shows up.
I think this does require some JS work to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

This would require JS. The problem that I see is that if you hover where the tooltip is, it'll show... whereas you only want the tooltip to show when you hover over divWithtooltip.

http://jsfiddle.net/oat19ncp/18/

The JS:

```
$('.divWithTooltip').hover(function() {
    $('.tooltip').stop(true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('.tooltip').stop(true).fadeOut();
});
```

The CSS:

```
.tooltip { 
    position:absolute ;
    bottom: -150px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:99;    
    height: 50px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: none;
}

.divWithTooltip {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding:5px; margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that tooltip inherited the :hover of it's parent .divWithTooltip. The conclusion is that the hover-element cannot be the parent of the tooltip. So I added an inner div and made that the hover-element instead which solved the issue http://jsfiddle.net/qvobx06x/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with just CSS. You could set a delay for the transitions and remove the tooltip by positioning it off screen.

So for the `.tooltip` set

```
left: -999em;
transition:opacity 0.5s linear 0.2s, left 0s linear 0.7s;
```

and for the the `:hover` rule

```
left: 10px;
transition:opacity 0.5s linear 0s, left 0s linear 0s;
```

This will instantly bring the tooltip in the screen when its parent is hovered, but delay the removal until it has faded out. (*and since it is off-screen it will not trigger a hover*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/oat19ncp/23/